# can this block of code be written in a shorter way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block of code, no complicated stuff is going on in it, and it is based on three different numbers ( viewport widths in my case ) :

```
if(viewport_width > 1224) {
    $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 8 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });
}
if(viewport_width < 1224 && viewport_width > 954) {
    $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 6 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });
}
if(viewport_width < 954 && viewport_width > 624) {
    $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 4 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });
}
if(viewport_width < 624) {
    $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 2 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });
}
```

So I though ( one method ) to place those three numbers in an array like this :

```
var widths = [1224, 954, 624];
```

And after apply an foreach function on it :

```
for(var i in widths ) {
   ...
}
```

But I cannot really figure how to wrap that up around those three numbers. The only thing that changes depending on the number in the array is another number :

```
{ ... perPage: 6 ... }
```

Which can vary from 8 down to 2. I would like a little help with this if possible, or maybe another way of writing it would be just fine.

Comment: Your conditions don't work: what happens if the width is EXACTLY 954? No condition?

Comment: You should test either for width > 954 and width < 955 or width > 954 and width < 955. And same with the other sizes.

Comment: I know that the conditions won't work in case that I get the exact widths ( till now I haven't even noticed ), but I wasn't looking for that, I wanted some insights on how I could approach those conditions in another way :) But thanks for the telling, I would have had some problems perhaps if you haven't told me :)

Comment: ok, very cool; check out the answer I suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make a list of objects:

```
var limits = [
  { min: 1224, perPage: 8 },
  { min: 954, perPage: 6 },
  { min: 624, perPage: 4 },
  { min: 0, perPage: 2 }
];
```

Then:

```
for (var i = 0; viewport_width <= limits[i].min, i++);
$(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: limits[i].perPage }, 
   function(pages){
      current_page = pages.current;
      total_pages = pages.count;
 });
```

Comment: I prefer this since I'm already using an object where I store other variables :)

Comment: So @Pointy, after testing this, it works, but if the maximum of the 1224px is exceeded the for loop doesn't act. So how can I rewrite the logic so it actually works, because often the width is more than 1224px ?

Comment: If the viewport width is greater than 1224px, then the loop will stop immediately with "i" equal to zero.  The "perPage" value will then be set to 8. Note that the comparison in the loop is `<= limits[i].min`; a width greater than 1224 will not be `<=` to 1224, so the no iterations are carried out.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Also why not encapsulating the block in curly braces after the for loop and instead using semicolons ? Also, inside the for conditions, isn't it suppose to be semicolon instead `,` before `i++`. Or is there a thing I did not knew about it ?

Comment: Assume that "viewport_width" is 2000.  What happens when the test expression in the loop is evaluated?  The value is `false`, so the loop exits immediately. The loop has no body at all; that's why there's just a semicolon. The "initiate_shop" call, in other words, is **not** part of the loop. The only thing the loop does is set the value of "i".

Comment: I see :)) Yes, indeed, because I tested for higher values and it jumped out of the loop, I mean the condition is not meet ever. I now understand the logic here. So I'm only looking for a value for `i` to set so then I can use it inside the plugin ... :) That's something new for me, I usually placed anything inside the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var page;
if (viewport_width > 1224) {
  page = 8;
} else if (viewport_width > 954) {
  page = 6;
} else if (viewport_width > 624) { 
  page = 4;
} else {
  page = 2;
}

$(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: page }, function(pages){
    current_page = pages.current;
    total_pages = pages.count;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like below,

Also Is it all `if..if..` or `else If`? I think it should be `if..else if..`

```
if(viewport_width > 1224) {
    initShop(pages, 8);
} else if(viewport_width >= 954) {
    initShop(pages, 6);
} else if(viewport_width >= 624) {
    initShop(pages, 4);
} else if(viewport_width < 624) {
    initShop(pages, 2);
}    

function initShop(pages,perPage) {
      $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 8 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });

}
```

Edit: updated `if..if` with `else if` as it makes more sense.. Also changed conditions to `>=` to cover all range.

---

**Orig Post:** containing all `if..if`

```
if(viewport_width > 1224) {
    initShop(pages, 8);
}
if(viewport_width < 1224 && viewport_width >= 954) {
    initShop(pages, 6);
}
if(viewport_width < 954 && viewport_width >= 624) {
    initShop(pages, 4);
}
if(viewport_width < 624) {
    initShop(pages, 2);
}    

function initShop(pages,perPage) {
      $(".shop-items-navigation").initiate_shop({ containerID: "shop-items-wrapper", perPage: 8 }, function(pages){
        current_page = pages.current;
        total_pages = pages.count;
    });
```

Comment: And what happens when width = 954?

Comment: @frenchie Question is **can this block of code be written in a shorter way?** so above is what I suggested..

Comment: @frenchie but you are right, his code didn't make much sense.. updated to cover all range.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense as it is, but I was looking for the shorter way thing. Anyway, I appreciate that someone told me about the mistake I made :)